# React SearchBar returning nothing once i clear my search bar after I search something

Tags: reactjs, react-table, searchbar

So currently I am trying to add a Search bar on top of my Table. My search bar and return data that is the same as what I typed in. But once clear the search bar and type something new in nothing return. I know it is because I am overriding my data when I am searching but don't know how to get the original data that I received from mongoDB back into table once I clear my search bar.

See below my code:

useStates as well as useEffect:

```
  const [data,setData] = React.useState([]);
  const [searched, setSearched] = React.useState("")

  //Getting user data
  React.useEffect(()=>{
    fetch("http://localhost:5000/staff/getStaffA")
        .then(resp=>resp.json())
        .then(data=>setData(data))

  },[]);
```

SearchBar inside that currently on top of my Table:

```
<SearchBar 
        style={{width:300 , float:'right'}}
        value={searched}
        onChange={(searchedVal)=>handleSearch(searchedVal)}
        onCancelSearch ={()=>cancelSearch()}
      />
```

Functions for handling search and canceling search:

```
//My search bar function
 const handleSearch = (value)=>{

  const filterRows = data.filter((row)=>{
    return (row.firstname.toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase()))||
           (row.lastname.toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase()))||
           (row.email.toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase()))||
           (row.telephoneNumber.toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase()))||
           (row.employeeManager.toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase()));
  });
    setData(filterRows)
  }
 
 //Cancel my search and return all data
 const cancelSearch = () =>{
   setSearched("");
   handleSearch(searched);
 }
```

The layout I am currently used I saw online but not working on my side.

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to set data as you type. You can filter data directly on the table.

`<Table columns={columns} data={data.filter(...)} />` solves your issue.